# Расширение/замена методов Java через код на JS

Tags: javascript, java, android, embedded

Я занимаюсь разработкой ответвления одного Android-рогалика, главной фичей которого должен стать моддинг (изменение поведения игры, добавление новых механик, вещей, персонажей). В текущий момент я склоняюсь к реализации этого через Rhino JavaScript.

Возможно ли заменять методы или поля Java-классов игры через код на JavaScript? Мне это нужно для модифицирования пользователем элементов оригинальной игры (другого выхода я не вижу).

Если такое невозможно (75% мне так кажется), то каким макаром можно сделать конструирование Java-кода из кода на другом языке, не обязательно JavaScript. Или мне нужно делать динамическую компиляцию и подгрузку классов на Java (тогда это заставит пользователя писать код на Java, что потенциальным пользователям-игрокам явно не понравится)?

Comment: Модифицировать это не верный и не реализуемый подход. Подумайте над другим решением. Как вариант хранение данных в БД. или файлов с мета-данными на самом устройстве. А уже ваш код будет выполнять ту или иную логику в зависимости от входных данных.

Comment: Мне бы хотелось дать пользователям полноценный молдинг аля Minecraft,  а не кучу файлов,  в которых нельзя приписывать логику.  Тут либо юзать BeanShell,  либо изобретать формат для описания этого хлама.